# Nuxt 2 Injecting Plugins & Typescript Dependencies - Error: relative module was not found: * ./index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&

Tags: nuxt.js

- `nuxt 2.15.8`
- `@nuxt/typescript-build 2.1.0`
- "typescript": "~4.2"

I am trying to follow the cookbook for Nuxt Typescript for plugins https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/plugins/
In my Nuxt project, I created a custom plugin file `/plugins/hello.ts`

```js
import { Plugin } from "@nuxt/types";
const helloPlugin: Plugin = (context, inject) => {
  inject("hello", () => alert("hello"));
};

export default helloPlugin;
```

And in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/hello']
```

but then I get this error:

[image]

```
This dependency was not found:                                                                      
* nuxt_plugin_hello_34b291c8 in ./.nuxt/index.js
```

and the `./.nuxt/index.js`

```js
import nuxt_plugin_plugin_8b6d7ab8 from 'nuxt_plugin_plugin_8b6d7ab8' // Source: .\\vuetify\\plugin.js (mode: 'all')
import nuxt_plugin_hello_785142de from 'nuxt_plugin_hello_785142de' // Source: ..\\plugins\\hello.ts (mode: 'client')
```

The cookbook doesn't mention registering the plugin in the `nuxt.config.js` but I presume that step is implied for Nuxt 2.

What might be wrong with the configuration? Do I need to specify a transpile of the file somewhere?

### Update

I tried adding a typescript based vue file and got this error:
`relative module was not found: * ./index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& in ./pages/index.vue`

So there is something wrong with the typescript tooling.

Comment: Try explicitly calling it plugins: ['~/plugins/hello.ts']

Comment: @Issayah thanks for the tip. It wasn't that, but I got it sorted out, and have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a dependency resolution issue of `typescript`.
My project doesn't have Vue files in typescript, the api and plugins are in typescript, and so I was chugging along with typescript tooling just fine until I tried tying it into the Nuxt tooling:

I had created the Nuxt project with the `create-nuxt-app` tool and then installed the packages with `npm` (7.23.0), and [typescript failing to be resolved correctly with Nuxt tooling is a known issue with `npm install` of the dependencies that `create-nuxt-app` adds to the package.json.](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/819)

The solution for me was to instead use `yarn` for the install ‍♂️ (dont you know yarn is better at dependency trees lol).
So I reinstalled the dependencies with yarn and then typescript was working with the Nuxt tooling, and the question's example plugin code all worked as it should.

*I updated the question to include the more common error people might encounter, and that is actually more revealing as to what the issue is.